# Not able to run Batch script in the background using GitHub Actions

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, github-actions

The command to run the batch script is:
START /B "batch.bat" & echo "Done."

The command runs and exits immediately in GitHub Actions without the batch file getting executed.
"Call" Command does not work in GitHub Actions.

Expected it to start the batch file and run continuously in the background.

Workflow:

```
name: Start 

on: workflow_dispatch 

jobs: 
  Start: 
    name: StartingServer 
    runs-on: [windows-machine-name] 
    steps: 
       - name: Run 
         run: | 
           echo "Starting the server" 
           echo "********" 
           START /B "batch.bat" & echo "Done." 
         shell: cmd
```

Comment: How are you running the command?

Comment: I am passing the command in the yml file in github action. The yml file looks like this:

name: Start

on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  Start:
    name: StartingServer
    runs-on: [windows-machine-name]
    steps:
      - name: Run
        run: |
          echo "Starting the server"
          echo "********"
          START /B "batch.bat" & echo "Done."
        shell: cmd

Comment: The questions I'd ask next are **1.** Why are you using the `/B` option with `START`, **2.** Why are you using `START`? _(Please open a Command Prompt window, type `start /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key, to see if it helps)_

Comment: The batch file runs continuously. I have used /b to start an application without opening a new Command Prompt window. I have used start because I have to run other batch files which also runs continuously. 
So the ideal scenario is, 3 batch files running continuously in the background through github actions.

Comment: We were looking to run a server and it needs to run in the background and the control needs to be back to the terminal to execute further commands. When we were looking for this requirements, we came across this option. If we can solve this without using /B flag, we would be ok with that as well.

Comment: All the command which include START and CALL command works in command prompt and powershell but doesnt work in Github Actions.

Answer (score 0):

[GitHub Actions does process tracking to ensure all processes created by GitHub Actions are properly killed when the step/workflow ends](https://github.com/actions/runner/blob/0e7ca9aedb2cf4ed792303c86b0598a43e773aa1/src/Runner.Sdk/ProcessInvoker.cs#L667).

If you need things to keep running you need to [start them as a scheduled task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks-create?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511) or windows service, that way the process won't be linked to the workflow.

> ### [To schedule a task to run now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks-create?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511#to-schedule-a-task-to-run-now)
>
> Schtasks doesn't have a Run Now option, but you can simulate that option by creating a task that runs once and starts in a few minutes.
>
> #### Example
>
> To schedule a task to run once, on November 13, 2020 at 2:18 P.M. local time, type:
>
> ```
> schtasks /create /tn MyApp /tr c:\apps\myapp.exe /sc once /st 14:18 /sd 11/13/2002
> ```
>
> In this example, the local computer uses the English (United States) option in Regional and Language Options, so the format for the start date is MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: Is there any other way to not include time? We want to run the GitHub workflow whenever there is a pull request

Comment: In your script read out the current time and set the value dynamically.