# Running a server in background using cmd shell for Windows

Tags: cmd, github-actions

I am trying to run a file called `CoreServer.exe` in the background using `cmd.exe` as mentioned [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell). When I specify the path of the server, it tells me,

```
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

On the other hand if I remove `shell: cmd` it works fine. But in this case it runs using `powershell.exe` and PowerShell is not what I want.

Here is my workflow file.

```
name: Test unit tests CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

  
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: windows-2022

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: setup Msbuild
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.3.1
      

#try nc -v -N 127.0.0.1 3334
 #curl http://localhost:3333 -I
 #vstest.console.exe ./Pico/Medman/FluidTransferTests/bin/Release/net481/FluidTransferTests.dll
#Start CoreServer.exe in background
    
    - name: Start CoreServer.exe in the background
      shell: cmd
      run: ./Debug/CoreServer.exe -c -s &

    - name: Wait 7 seconds
      run: sleep 7

    - name: See status
      run: netstat -ntp
```

To add more information, when I run `CoreServer.exe` in a Command Prompt, on my local machine, it runs fine, and shows the following:

[image: CoreServer.exe -c -s]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The windows shell doesn't handle linux style path separators. `./debug` *must* be `.\debug`, that will remove the error.

```
    - name: Start CoreServer.exe in the background
      shell: cmd
      run: .\Debug\CoreServer.exe -c -s &
```

It's generally not recommended to run things in the background this way. It's better to [run a service container alongside the job](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/about-service-containers).

[The runner will kill any processes that are launched by a step](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75821066/736079).

[There is a way to work around the process-killing feature by resetting the environment variable that tracks the process identifiers](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/598).

In Windows command shell this should look like:

```
    # ⚠️ untested
    - name: Start CoreServer.exe in the background
      shell: cmd
      run: |
          set RUNNER_TRACKING_ID=""
          .\Debug\CoreServer.exe -c -s &
```

Or by combining all of the elements into a single script step:

```
    - name: Start CoreServer.exe in the background
      shell: cmd
      run: |
        .\Debug\CoreServer.exe -c -s &
        sleep 7
        netstat -ntp
```

Comment: It works thank you. But its not starting the CoreServer.exe as a background task.